# Drawing A rectangle based on user Touch in android OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch, rectangles, vertices

I am able to draw a rectangle in android openGL using

```
private float vertices[] = {

                -1.0f, 0.8f,  0.0f,        // V1 - bottom left

                -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,        // V2 - top left

        1.0f, 0.8f,  0.0f,        // V3 - bottom right

        1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f         // V4 - top right

};
```

But i want to give vertices based on user Touch using event.getX() and event.getY(). Those values seem to make the rectangle go out of the screen.
How do i see that the rectangle is drawn where the user touches?

Comment: Change your view to [orthographic mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6585867/2304737). You should figure out the next step.

Comment: Suppose my event.getX() is 200 px i.e from left of screen.....and event.getY() is 300 px from top of screen..... how do i mention the vertices of my rectangle in floats according to android open gl to draw a rectangle from (200,300) to (200+100,300+100)... can you give me some sample code...??? @ genpfault

Comment: @kaushikreddy may be late, but did you found the solution for this?